# Revert a change made in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame called x. Now, I wanted to create a new column using mutate. I know how mutate works.

```
x <- x %>%
  mutate(column3 = column1+column2)
```

Now I also needed to select just 3rd column. Unfortunately, I piped the select statement too.

```
x <- x %>%
  mutate(column3 = column1+column2) %>%
  select(column3)
```

Resulting just 1 column in my data frame. I want to revert this change made. Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `transmute` to output a single column

```
x <- x %>%
       transmute(column3 = column1+column2)
```

But, if we have already assigned an object with the output, it is not possible to go back to the original dataset unless we load the data again or create a `copy` of the original dataset before we do the assignment.

#### data

```
x <- data.frame(column1 = 1:5, column2 = 6:10)
library(data.table)
x1 <- copy(x)
```

Comment: is there any advantage of `x1<- copy(x)` over `x1<-x`?

Comment: @DavidPell  In case you are doing some transformation using `data.table`, by doing `copy` it will not change the 'x1'